# INDEX usage different - Got the Solution

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I tried to run one SQL query giving where condition directly (it is working faster).

```
WHERE A = '1234'
```

But passing the variable its taking more time.

```
SET @VAL = '1234'
WHERE A = @VAL
```

And the EXPLAIN parameter also show different key fields.  What could be the reason?

Fast one (giving constant directly)

```
--------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys                                               | key                    | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra                                  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tracking           | ref    | unique-guest_user,FK4BBA1EB7AFA8C3E7,browser_id_hash_search | browser_id_hash_search | 257     | const                       |    3 | Using index condition; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mn_connected_users | eq_ref | user_id                                                     | user_id                | 4       | 20131123_b.tracking.user_id |    1 | Using where                            |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

Slow one (giving the constant value through variable)

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys                        | key               | key_len | ref                         | rows   | Extra                                     |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tracking           | index  | unique-guest_user,FK4BBA1EB7AFA8C3E7 | unique-guest_user | 522     | NULL                        | 248724 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mn_connected_users | eq_ref | user_id                              | user_id           | 4       | 20131123_b.tracking.user_id |      1 | Using where                               |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Solution:

I declared as VARCHAR only, but its not working. But i got the solution now. CONVERT(A USING latin1) is used to resolve the problem. I gave this in Where condition. Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the data type of `A`?

Comment: Sounds like some performance is lost converting data types or character sets. Have you tried declaring the data type before using it. Like: `declare @VAL as varchar(8)` or whatever type you're querying?

Comment: I declared as VARCHAR only,  but its not working.                    But i got the solution now.   CONVERT(A USING latin1) is used to resolve the problem.  I gave this in Where condition.                       Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3080572, glad it's working. You can either delete the question or write your own answer. This will stop others wasting time solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I declared as VARCHAR only, but its not working. But i got the solution now. CONVERT(A USING latin1) is used to resolve the problem. I gave this in Where condition. Thanks for the help – user3080572